# LINQ Joining Multiple Tables - No Results

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to use LINQ to join multiple tables, and retrieve the name of a distribution method.  I have a SQL statement I used as a basis, which follows.

```
  select dt.NAME 
  from i_doc.dbo.document as d
  join i_doc.dbo.CONTACT as c
  on c.DOC_ID = d.DOC_ID 
  join i_doc.dbo.RECIPIENT as r
  on r.CONTACT_ID = c.CONTACT_ID 
  join i_doc.dbo.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE as dt
  on dt.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE_ID = r.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE_ID 
  where c.CONTACT_TYPE_ID = 2
  and r.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE_ID != 6
  and d.DOC_ID = 28757
```

This particular query returns 1 item.  However, the LINQ code I have returns nothing.  The LINQ code follows.

```
var distributionMethod = (from d in _documentEntities.DOCUMENTs
                                  join c in _documentEntities.CONTACTs on d.DOC_ID equals c.DOC_ID
                                  join r in _documentEntities.RECIPIENTs on c.CONTACT_ID equals r.CONTACT_ID
                                  join dt in _documentEntities.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE on r.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE_ID equals dt.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE_ID
                                  where c.CONTACT_ID == 2
                                  && r.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE_ID != 6
                                  && d.DOC_ID == DocID
                                  select dt.NAME).ToList();
```

When trying to determine what was going on we simplified the query to test if the connection was being made correctly, and tested the following LINQ.

```
var test = (from dt in _documentEntities.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE           
                                  select dt.NAME).Take(100);
```

This LINQ, var test, results in the appropriate values.

My question is:  Why is my distributionMethod LINQ query not returning anything, and what can I do to fix it?

Thank You

Comment: Well, that makes me feel stupid.....If you would like credit for the answer to my specific problem, feel free to include an answer, and I will mark it as Answered and complete.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LINQ query you filter by `c.CONTACT_ID`, but in SQL query you filter by `c.CONTACT_TYPE_ID`, so that's just simple typo.

Comment: If it's a typo shouldn't you vote to close instead of giving an answer?

Comment: Yes after exploring possible close reasons I see that typos that might not help future readers must be closed, so voted for that.